# Scope of implicits

Tags: scala, scope, implicit

As a follow up to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526345/unambiguous-subimplicits), see comments / questions in code:

```
case class Implicit(name: String)

def foo(implicit i: Implicit = null) = println(Option(i))

def bar1(implicit i: Implicit) {
  foo // prints None
  implicit val i = Implicit("J") // Why is call to foo above affected although this line comes after?
  foo // prints Some(Implicit(I))
}

def bar2(implicit i: Implicit) {
  foo // prints None
  implicit val i = null
  implicit val j = Implicit("J")
  foo // prints None // Why? Should raise ambiguous implicits or at least choose j.
}

def bar3(implicit i: Implicit) {
  foo // prints None
  val i = null
  implicit val j = Implicit("J")
  foo // prints Some(Implicit(J)) // Now it works as I expected to work in bar2.
}

def bar4(implicit i: Implicit) { // That's how I expected to see bar1 working. A ugly hack here. 
  foo // prints Some(Implicit(I))
  locally {
    val i = null
    implicit val j = Implicit("J")
    foo // prints Some(Implicit(J))
  }
}

val i = Implicit("I")
bar1(i)
bar2(i)
bar3(i)
bar4(i)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code suffers from name shadowing. The spec in [chapter 2](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html) says about this:

> A binding has a scope in which the entity defined by a single name can be accessed using a simple name. Scopes are nested. **A binding in some inner scope shadows bindings of lower precedence in the same scope as well as bindings of the same or lower precedence in outer scopes.**

In your example, this means that with

```
def foo(implicit i: Implicit) = println(Option(i))
```

we have the following possibilities:

1. The implicit param `i` gets passed to `foo` because `x` would be a forward reference:

   ```
   scala> def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {foo; implicit val x = Implicit("i")}
   f: (implicit i: Implicit)Unit
   ```
2. Nothing can be passed to `foo` because parameter `i` is shadowed by the local value `i` which has higher precedence but can't be called because it is a forward reference.

   ```
   scala> def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {foo; implicit val i = Implicit("i")}
   <console>:11: error: could not find implicit value for parameter i: Implicit
          def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {foo; implicit val i = Implicit("i")}
                                         ^
   ```
3. A value is shadowed when it has the same name, but it must not have the same type:

   ```
   scala> def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {implicit val j = Implicit("i"); foo}
   <console>:11: error: ambiguous implicit values:
    both value i of type Implicit
    and value j of type Implicit
    match expected type Implicit
          def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {implicit val j = Implicit("i"); foo}
                                                                         ^

   scala> def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {val i = null; implicit val j = Implicit("i"); foo}
   f: (implicit i: Implicit)Unit
   ```
4. There exists multiple implicits in scope, but one has higher precedence. In this case `i` has the higher precedence because `Null <: Implicit`

   ```
   scala> def f(implicit i: Implicit) = {implicit val i = null; implicit val j = Implicit("i"); foo}
   f: (implicit i: Implicit)Unit
   ```

Your definition of `foo` was declared with a default value for the implicit parameter. This doesn't change anything at the rules mentioned above, but the compiler can choose the default value when no other value is available.

Comment: Interesting! Especially 3. (must not have same type) and 4.! What is the reason that `i` has higher precedence because `Null <: Implicit`? Is `Null` more "specific" or what is the rule? I am not able to annotate the inferred `Null` type, this raises an error: `def f(implicit i: Implicit) = { foo; implicit val i: Null = null }`

Comment: The rule is that a subtype has always higher precedence than a supertype. This is why for types `A; B<:A; C<:A` the expression `List(B,C)` is of type `List[A]` and not `List[Any]` or something else. And it is obvious why your example doesn't work, it conflicts with rule 2.